# Authentication Required error while sending email using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to send email using following PHP code.But I get the following error:

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257

```
<?php
    $to = "jaynanavati@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "jaynanavati@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477902/mail-php-smtp-authentication-issue

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty obvious that your SMTP server requires you to authenticate. Use a more powerful tool for sending mail, such as PHPMailer.